# Load data from file and normalize

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, classification, knn

How to normalize data loaded from file? Here what I have. Data looks kind of like this:

```
65535, 3670, 65535, 3885, -0.73, 1
65535, 3962, 65535, 3556, -0.72, 1
```

Last value in each line is a target. I want to have the same structure of the data but with normalized values.

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtxt('infrared_data.txt', delimiter=',')

# select first 5 columns as the data
X = dataset[:, 0:5]

# is that correct? Should I normalize along 0 axis?
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(X, axis=0)

y = dataset[:, 5]
```

Now the question is, how to pack correctly `normalized_X` and `y` back, that it has the structure:

```
dataset = [[normalized_X[0], y[0]],[normalized_X[1], y[1]],...]
```

Comment: `np` looks like a module (I assume `numpy`!?). Please tag your question with it. That, on the one hand, helps people to better understand the question, on the other hand, get the attention of people with a more profound knowledge about this. :)

Comment: For the question (i got no `numpy`, so I don't know, whether this works): `dataset = [a + [b] for a, b in zip(normalized_X, y)]` (no guarantee!)

Comment: Thank you. Almost there. The output is:
`[(array([ 1.    ,  0.0202,  1.    ,  0.0455,  0.2121]), 1.0), (array([ 1.    ,  0.0301,  1.    ,  0.0255,  0.2273]), 1.0)]`. How to get rid of this `array()` and make the elements of outer tuple just coma separated?

Comment: yeah. as I said: `numpy`. in normal python it would have worked. `dataset = [magic_function_to_convert_to_normal_list(a) + [b] for a, b in zip(normalized_X, y)]` ^^ but I would not recommend it, as you would loose the magic of `numpy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html).  For example, let's set up some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
y = np.arange(5) + 1000
```

Which gives us:

```
X:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
Y:
array([1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004])
```

And we want:

```
new = np.column_stack([x, y])
```

Which gives us:

```
New:
array([[   0,    1,    2,    3,    4, 1000],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,    9, 1001],
       [  10,   11,   12,   13,   14, 1002],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19, 1003],
       [  20,   21,   22,   23,   24, 1004]])
```

If you'd prefer less typing, you can also use:

```
In [4]: np.c_[x, y]
Out[4]:
array([[   0,    1,    2,    3,    4, 1000],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,    9, 1001],
       [  10,   11,   12,   13,   14, 1002],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19, 1003],
       [  20,   21,   22,   23,   24, 1004]])
```

However, I'd discourage using `np.c_` for anything other than interactive use, simply due to readability concerns.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you. Can you also advise me how to format the results printed to be e.g. `1, 2, 3` instead of `1.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 3.0000e+00`